# Python String adjust

Tags: python, string

Hello is use some method like .isupper() in a loop, or string[i+1] to find my lower char but i don't know how to do that

```
input in function -> "ThisIsMyChar"
expected -> "This is my char"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I´ve done it with regex, could be done with less code but my intention is readable

```
import re

def split_by_upper(input_string):
    pattern = r'[A-Z][a-z]*'
    matches = re.findall(pattern, input_string)
    if (matches):
        output = matches[0]
        for word in matches[1:]:
            output += ' ' + word[0].lower() + word[1:]
        return output
    else:
        return input_string


print(split_by_upper("ThisIsMyChar"))
>> split_by_upper() -> "This is my char"
```

Comment: Hey, I´m new on trying to help on Stackoverflow, I´m trying to improve on my answers so feedback would be nice

Comment: OkOk thanks you i understand how to do now ;)

The other response are really good but i don't understand really good what happend, i need train myself with regex ^^'

Answer (score 1):

You could use `re.findall` and `str.lower`:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'ThisIsMyChar'
>>> ' '.join(w.lower() if i >= 1 else w for i, w in enumerate(re.findall('.[^A-Z]*', s)))
'This is my char'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should first try by yourself. If you didn't get it done, you can do something like this:

```
# to parse input string
def parse(str):
  result= "" + str[0];
  for i in range(1, len(str)):
    ch = str[i]
    if ch.isupper():
      result += " ";
    result += ch.lower();
  return result;

# input string
str  = "ThisIsMyChar";
print(parse(str))
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to run a for loop and check for Uppercase words then when you find it just add a space at the starting, lower the word and increment it to your new string. Simple, more code is explained in comments in the code itself.

```
def AddSpaceInTitleCaseString(string):
    NewStr = ""

    # Check for Uppercase string in the input string char-by-char.
    for i in string:
        # If it found one, add it to the NewStr variable with a space and lowering it's case.
        if i.isupper(): NewStr += f" {i.lower()}"

        # Else just add it as usual.
        else: NewStr += i

    # Before returning the NewStr, remove all the leading and trailing spaces from it.
    # And as shown in your question I'm assuming that you want the first letter or your new sentence,
    # to be in uppercase so just use 'capitalize' function for it.
    return NewStr.strip().capitalize()

# Test.
MyStr = AddSpaceInTitleCaseString("ThisIsMyChar")
print(MyStr)

# Output: "This is my char"
```

Hope it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

You can split it via Regex using `r"(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])"` pattern:

```py
import re

txt = 'ThisIsMyChar'
c = re.compile(r"(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])")

first, *rest = map(str.lower, c.split(txt))
print(f'{first.title()} {" ".join(rest)}')
```

Pattern explanation:
`(?<!^)` checks to see if it is not at the beginning.
`(?=[A-Z])` checks to see there a capital letter after it.

**note** These are non-capturing groups.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a concise regex solution:

```
import re

capital_letter_pattern = re.compile(r'(?!^)[A-Z]')

def add_spaces(string):
    return capital_letter_pattern.sub(lambda match: ' ' + match[0].lower(), string)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(add_spaces('ThisIsMyChar'))
```

The pattern searches for capital letters (`[A-Z]`), and the `(?!^)` is negative lookahead that excludes the first character of the input (`(?!foo)` means "don't match `foo`, `^` is "start of line", so `(?!^)` is "don't match start of line").

The `.sub(...)` method of a pattern is usually used like `pattern.sub('new text', 'my input string that I want changed')`. You can also use a function in place of `'new text'`, in which case the function is called with the match object as an argument, and the value returned by the function is used as the replacement string.

The expression `capital_letter_pattern.sub(lambda match: ' ' + match[0].lower(), string)` replaces all matches (all capital letters except at the start of the line) using a lambda function to add a space before and make the letter lowercase. `match[0]` means "the entirety of the matched text", which in this case is the captial letter.